# How to access a value in a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a window with the following elements, and I'm trying to access the value contained in `<TextBlock Name="armingValue"` but in my .xaml.cs file it doesn't seem to be recognised.

What do I need to do to access the value?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ArmingVM:ArmingItem}">
        <CheckBox Margin="10,5" IsChecked="{Binding IsSet}" Content="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ArmingVM:ArmingBindingData}">
        <DockPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ArmingItems}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
            <TextBlock Text="Enum Value: " HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <TextBlock Name="armingValue" Text="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="193*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="551*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Content="Get Panel Options" Name="btnGetOptionsConfigruation" Margin="12,12,23,396" Click="btnGetOptionsConfigruation_Click"></Button>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Height="325" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,43,0,0" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="438">
        <ItemsControl Name="armingItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not recognised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to access TextBox value but its **binded** value.
So considering that you have in `XAML`

```
 <TextBlock Name="armingValue" Text="{Binding Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
```

You need to read a `Value`

Try always to avoid access UI elements directly in `WPF`, cause sometimes (not so rare cases) it becomes *really* tricky to find them if not imossible (I mean not guranteed way). Access a *Data* that stands behind them.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I suppose my next question is how do I access that value? In my .xaml.cs file, I access the `armingItemsControl` is bound to `options.ArmingBindingData`, which is retreived on a button click from a service. Should I widen the scope of the `options` object so that it's available in other event handlers (e.g. `btnSave_Click()` where the value is needed?

Answer (score 1):

The backing variables generated by visual studio within the `.xaml.cs` file are only generated for certain circumstances. Any 'named' element within the body of a user control will have a generated backing variable. However, named elements within templates will not be generated. This is because Visual Studio has no way of knowing how your template will be used. For example, your template could be used by an `ItemsControl` to generate multiple template instances. What should be generated within `.xaml.cs` in that case?

You have two options:

1. Use binding, so that the state of your `TextBlock.Text` property is bound to a view model, so that you do not have to access the `TextBlock` element directly.
2. 'walk' the visual tree to locate your `TextBlock` at runtime.

For (2), I would suggest using [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), where you can find your `TextBlock` as follows:

```
TextBlock block = layoutRoot.Descendants<TextBlock>()
                            .Cast<TextBlock>().Where(tb => tb.Name="armingValue")
                            .Single();
```

Comment: it doesn't always work, especially working with templates and even if yes it's extremely addicted to failure, cause toughly coupled to UI layout that can changed especially during development process. In other words, not reliable way to access a data, should be choosen *only* if there is no other way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not get the point but why don't you create a binding to textbox and mark it as two way?

```
<TextBlock Text="Enum Value: " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: @Tigran I think for TextBlock.Text TwoWay is not the default binding

Comment: @Tigran From msdn: "One of the BindingMode values. The default is Default, which returns the default binding mode value of the target dependency property. However, the default value varies for each dependency property. In general, user-editable control properties, such as those of text boxes and check boxes, default to two-way bindings, whereas most other properties default to one-way bindings."